# Is there anyway to refill a repair tool outside of a garage?

Tags: snowrunner

There's a few a truck attachment which allow your vehicles to performs repairs on themselves and other vehicles. Doing so works similar to the refueling attachments, where each repair has a fixed number of repair it can use before it runs out. For a refueling tank you can always refill it at a gas station, or just with another vehicle. So far I haven't found anyway to refill a repair attachment outside of returning to a garage.

Is there any way to refill a repair attachment outside of a garage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repair points can be fully restored by driving through the loading zone of a Service Hub. This will also fully repair your vehicle.

[image]

Comment: I've driven through the repair zone/service hub 14 times with the towed yellow maintenance trailer hooked to the back of my truck on Michigan Dam map, it neither repairs anything, refills anything, nor refuel anything.