# How to reload/refuel maintenance trailers?

Tags: snowrunner

I've driven through the service hub repair zone near the garage 14 times with the towed yellow maintenance trailer hooked to the back of my truck on Michigan Dam map, but it's not repairing, refueling, or refilling anything.

All my research online (including on  [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/369488/is-there-anyway-to-refill-a-repair-tool-outside-of-a-garage)) indicates that driving through the repair zone in a service hub with a vehicle will repair it, refill it, and the maintenance trailer attached will be restocked and refueled. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue?